# Arduino Uno pin response speed

Tags: arduino, timing, output

We are attempting to build a coilgun with multiple coils, and each coil needs to be energized and deenergized at precise time intervals. For cost (and inexperience) reasons, we are considering using an Arduino Uno for this task. Our questions are as follows:

How quickly can the Uno toggle a pin between states?
How consistent is the timing?
Is there a better option, keeping in mind our inexperience and lack of funds?

Comment: 1 to 3.  Still deciding.

Comment: Toggling can be as quick as a single instruction, and, if all interrupts are disabled, can be as consistent as the crystal used to clock the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

If you need pulses repeated at regular intervals, i.e. a pulse-width-modulated (PWM) signal, using the hardware timers on the ATmega328 might be the way to go. This gives you very precise and consistent timing and allows you to toggle a pin as fast as \$f_{CPU}/2\$ (8 MHz on an Arduino Uno), but it pretty much restricts your waveform to "high for X cycles out of Y".

This [Arduino article](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM) has an overview of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what the CPU allows us to do. The following is a the off-the-shelf C code for toggling a pin as quickly as possible:

```
while (1) PORTA ^= 0x01;
```

If the compiler was smart enough, it would compile into following:

```
  ldi r25, 0x01    ; Load immediate

start:
  eor r24, r25     ; r24 = r24 XOR r25
  out 0x02, r24    ; Out (store) to IO location
  rjmp .-6         ; Goto start
```

I'd say this is pretty much the fastest loop on an AVR you can get. Now, let's take each instruction's execution time:

- OUT - 1 cycle
- EOR - 1 cycle
- RJMP - 2 cycles

This totals to 4 cycles. Note that this is a single pin toggle. To get the switching frequency, multiply by 2. Taking into account your CPU speed of 16 MHz, you can therefore say that the fastest you can toggle a pin on a mega AVR is \$f_{max} = f_{CPU}/8\$

---

This, of course, makes the rate pretty much uncontrollable, since the smallest step you can decrease the period is a single CPU cycle, for example by adding a NOP instruction into the mix.

For toggling a pin there are much more elegant solutions. I'd suggest reading about the 555 timer. You're likely to catch some wind there.

Comment: Timers would be used for very fast toggling, not code loops.

Comment: In fact, there is a faster way to toggle pins through code in most AVRs: Writing an `1` to a bit in the PINx register will toggle the pin value, so you can do without the XOR.

Answer (score 0):

This started as a comment but there was no nice way to format it...

I found (albeit on a different MCU - Coldfire for those who're interested) that using

```
PORTn ^= 1;
```

Is actually a **lot** slower than writing directly to either the `PORTnSET` or `PORTnCLR` registers, as it involves a read/logical-operation/write sequence.

To explain, the micro has several registers for each port (I don't know how common this is across all micros), but the popular general-purpose PORTn one (that can be used to set, clear, or read the pin state) sits "above" the lower-level trio of PORTnSET, CLR or STATE which, in order, can either SET the pin (1 = set, 0 = no change), CLEAR (1 = clear, 0 = no change) or READ the raw pin state (reading the others is not a guarantee as the register state may not be applied if the pin is configured as input etc.).

We found the `PORTn ^= 1` resulted in a lot of lines of assembly from the compiler, which was indeed causing our pulses to be far too long.

If you are aiming for a single quick pulse it would be faster to do:

```
PORTnCLR = 1; // Clears pin
<wait for button push or whatever>
PORTnSET = 1; // Sets pin
PORTnCLR = 1; // Clears pin
```

I don't know how fast you need to go, but it seems to me that there should be some simple analogue way of providing a VERY sharp trigger pulse (if the width of the pulse has to be as narrow as possible) with a few basic bits.

There are also better options micro-wise if you need the sequencing capability, STM32 dev boards can be had up to ~192MHz for less than an Ardunio, and then you can learn some real programming too.

A good start would be the Linear Tech appnote archives as there is some brilliant stuff from the likes of Bob Pease & Jim Williams in there:

http://www.linear.com/doclist/

Answer (score -1):

The arduino uno uses a 16MHz crystal which means that it's capable of doing 16 million instructions in a second.

It depends on how long your script is how fast the arduino will toggle your pin high and low.

---

Never mind this answer seems to be wrong. My bad

Comment: Note: 16 million instructions is only theoretical in fact it will be a bit lower

Comment: 16 million instruction *cycles* per second: Some instructions take more than one cycle. Also, if interrupts are enabled, productive cycles for the foreground code would reduce.

Comment: I didn't say instruction cycles. Just instructions. Turning a led on is already 1 instruction. Turning it off is a second instruction. The loop itself is an instruction.

Comment: Exactly, and that was your error: An instruction can take more than one cycle, and yet the microcontroller with a 16 MHz crystal delivers merely 16 million instruction cycles per second, *not* 16 million instructions, unless you are assuming that only single-cycle instructions are to be used - which, if you were to examine the instruction timings of the AtMega even cursorily, will prove to be unlikely.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the explanation. I'm still a student on electronics and had poor lessons from my college. So I had to find most things out by my self. Getting feedback like this will help me understanding things better ;)